# Using third party components in Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install classes or units like components in Delphi 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537414/how-to-install-classes-or-units-like-components-in-delphi-2007)

1. Any one please tell me how to use third party components (such as
   ALPHA Skins )in DELPHI 2007.
2. How to Install it?

Comment: http://delphi.about.com/library/howto/htinstallcomponent.htm http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Install_Components

Comment: please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537414/how-to-install-classes-or-units-like-components-in-delphi-2007 And also this http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Install_Components

Answer (score 3):

Here I'll try to describe you how to install the [`AlphaSkins`](http://alphaskins.com/sfiles/alite.zip) package, but this is the common way how to install packages. It's described for Delphi 2007.

About your specific request for AlphaSkins; you can follow the `Install.txt` file included in the `zip` archive or you might follow this more detailed workflow:

- create a directory wherever you want, I have created `c:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\AlphaSkins\`
- unpack the whole content of the `zip` archive into that directory
- open Delphi and go to the `Tools\Options` menu, in the opened dialog go to the `Environment Options\Delphi Options\Library - Win32` and click on the browse button `...` beside the `Library path` edit box; the `Directories` dialog will popup
- insert your new created directory into the edit box in `Directories` dialog, click on the `Add` button and close both dialogs by clicking on the `OK` buttons
- show the `Project Manager` window from menu `View\Project Manager`
- now open the runtime package using `File\Open...` menu item and open the file `c:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\AlphaSkins\D2007\acnt2007_R.dpk`
- go to the `Project Manager` window, click the right mouse button on the `acnt2007_R.bpl` tree view item and select `Compile` popup menu item, close the compilation dialog
- now open the design time package using `File\Open...` menu item and open the file `c:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\AlphaSkins\D2007\acnt2007.dpk`
- go to the `Project Manager` window, click the right mouse button on the `acnt2007.bpl` tree view item and select `Install` popup menu item, the information window should popup with the info about new installed components
- close the info dialog, select `File\Close All` and discard the changes (don't save)

You have to specify also the path to the source codes (`*.pas` and `*.dcu` files), without doing it, you won't compile the project:

- go to the `Tools\Options` menu, in the opened dialog go to the `Environment Options\Delphi Options\Library - Win32` and click on the browse button `...` beside the `Library path` edit box; the `Directories` dialog will popup
- insert the `c:\Program Files (x86)\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\lib\AlphaSkins\D2007\` directory into the edit box, click on the `Add` button and close both dialogs by clicking on the `OK` buttons
- create some VCL project and enjoy the AlphaSkins components!